# Restoring 1998 FTM files?

Tags: family-tree-maker

I am using Windows 10.  Cannot open my FTM files.  They no longer have the right extension.  All my 1998 FTM files now have *.CLT extension.

How can I recover all the files?

Answer (score 1):

> They no longer have the right extension. All my 1998 FTM files now have *.CLT extension.

No mention on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filename_extensions_(A%E2%80%93E)#C) of any CLT file extension for FTM or on the [Just Solve the File Format Problem](http://justsolve.archiveteam.org/wiki/Family_Tree_Maker) website?

[file.org](https://file.org/extension/clt) mentions that *.clt could be for associated with **Visual Basic application development software** and also **dBASE IV Aldus software program**

Here is a link to ["Moving old Mac and Windows files to FTM 2017 for Windows"](https://www.mackiev.com/ftm/ftmtransferkit/Tree_File_Moving_Guide_Win.pdf)  PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I recently was in a similar situation - found a binder with Family Tree Maker 1.01 and a data diskette with 3 *.FTM files that have dates from 1991 (2 of the 3 files were recovered - still working on #3).
[This post](https://www.ancestry.com/boards/topics.software.famtreemaker/12448.1.1/mb.ashx) gives a pointer to downloading FTM for Windows 2005, which will allow you to open .FTM files, then save them either as .FTW (Family Tree Maker - WIndows) or .GED (standard GEDCOM file format, which can be read into other geneology programs).
So far, it seems that the [Open Source Webtrees](https://www.webtrees.net/index.php/en/) project is pretty feature complete, but I'm a geneology newbie.

Best of luck.

> > update: sorry, just re-read your post...maybe use FTM 2005 to open your .FTM files, then save as .GED?